# Present e-mail keyboard on smartphones but don't validate and stop submitting

Tags: html, validation, email, input

I'm using the following form to send an e-mail address:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I set `type="email"` instead of simply `type="text"` because this will present a keyboard on smartphones that is especially for typing an e-mail address. (E.g. the `@` character is easier to access.)

Unfortunately, this will validate the e-mail address on submit. It will prompt `Enter e-mail address` and stop submitting in case this isn't an e-mail address.

I want to make it easy to type an e-mail address by presenting the fitting keyboard but without forcing the user to insert an e-mail address and pay attention not to write e.g. a space by mistake.

How can I reach that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add the `novalidate=""` attribute to the `<form>` like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate="">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```